# bash: find pattern in one file and apply some code for each pattern found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I created a script that will auto-login to router and checks for current CPU load, if load exceeds a certain threshold I need it print the current CPU value to the standard output.

i would like to search in script o/p for a certain pattern (the value 80 in this case which is the threshold for high CPU load) and then for each instance of the pattern it will check if current value is greater than 80 or not, if true then it will print 5 lines before the pattern followed by then the current line with the pattern.

Question1: how to loop over each instance of the pattern and apply some code on each of them separately?

Question2: How to print n lines before the pattern followed by x lines after the pattern?

ex. i used awk to search for the pattern "health" and print 6 lines after it as below:

```
 awk '/health/{x=NR+6}(NR<=x){print}' ./logs/CpuCheck.log
```

I would like to do the same for the pattern "80" and this time print 5 lines before it and one line after....only if $3 (representing current CPU load) is exceeding the value 80

below is the output of auto-login script (file name: CpuCheck.log)

```
ABCD-> show health xxxxxxxxxx
* - current value exceeds threshold

                                1 Min  1 Hr  1 Hr
Cpu                Limit   Curr   Avg    Avg   Max
-----------------+-------+------+------+-----+----
01                   80     39     36    36    47

WXYZ-> show health xxxxxxxxxx
* - current value exceeds threshold

                                1 Min  1 Hr  1 Hr
Cpu                Limit   Curr   Avg    Avg   Max
-----------------+-------+------+------+-----+----
01                   80     29     31    31    43
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: awk can certainly do it. One other way is to use `grep`, the `-A` flag controls how many lines **after** the match that will be displayed and `-B` how many lines **before**.

Comment: In awk the easiest way would be to read the file twice. Set markers in the first loop and then print between the markers in the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `awk` is stream-oriented and doesn't have a simple way to get the lines before the current line. But that doesn't mean it isn't possible:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        bufferSize = 6;
    }
    {
        buffer[NR % bufferSize] = $0;
    }
    $2 == 80 && $3 > 80 {
        # print the five lines before the match and the line with the match
        for (i = 1; i <= bufferSize; i++) {
            print buffer[(NR + i) % bufferSize];
        }
    }
' ./logs/CpuCheck.log
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me....I modified the threshold to check in case more than one line is matching the condition and i have the desired output

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use awk, you could use the `-B` and `-A` and  switches to grep, which print a number of lines before and after a pattern is matched:

```
grep -E -B 5 -A 1 '^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+80[[:space:]]+(100|9[0-9]|8[1-9])' CpuCheck.log
```

The pattern matches lines which start with some numbers, followed by spaces, followed by 80, followed by a number greater between 81 and 100. The `-E` switch enables extended regular expressions (EREs), which are needed if you want to use the `+` character to mean "one or more". If your version of grep doesn't support EREs, you can instead use the slightly more verbose `\{1,\}` syntax:

```
grep -B 5 -A 1 '^[0-9]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}80[[:space:]]\{1,\}\(100\|9[0-9]\|8[1-9]\)' CpuCheck.log
```

If grep isn't an option, one alternative would be to use awk. The easiest way would be to store all of the lines in a buffer:

```
awk 'f-->0;{a[NR]=$0}/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+80[[:space:]]+(100|9[0-9]|8[1-9])/{for(i=NR-5;i<=NR;++i)print i, a[i];f=1}'
```

This stores every line in an array `a`. When the third column is greater than 80, it prints the previous 5 lines from the array. It also sets the flag `f` to 1, so that `f-->0` is true for the next line, causing it to be printed.

Originally I had opted for a comparison `$3>80` instead of the regular expression but this isn't a good idea due to the varying format of the lines.

If the log file is really big, meaning that reading the whole thing into memory is unfeasible, you could implement a circular buffer so that only the previous 5 lines were stored, or alternatively, read the file twice.

Comment: Unfortunately my grep version doesn't support -B or -A options.

Comment: @tom how do you propose printed the following line then?

Comment: @TomFenech If you use f as well then it will print overlapping lines multiple times

Comment: @JID you're right, although it doesn't look like that would be an issue based on the sample input.

Comment: @A.Midany if your problem is solved, don't forget to accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way with awk, by reading the file.
This should use essentially 0 memory except whatever is used to store the line numbers.

If there is only one occurence

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&$2=="80"{to=NR+1;from=NR-5}NR!=FNR&&FNR<=to&&FNR>=from' file{,}
```

If there are more than one occurences

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&$2=="80"{to[++x]=NR+1;from[x]=NR-5}
     NR!=FNR{for(i in to)if(FNR<=to[i]&&FNR>=from[i]){print;next}}' file{,}
```

---

#### Input/output

`Input`

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
01                   80     39     36    36    47
13
14
15
16
17
01                   80     39     36    36    47
18
19
20
```

`Output`

```
8
9
10
11
12
01                   80     39     36    36    47
13
14
15
16
17
01                   80     39     36    36    47
18
```

---

#### How it works

```
NR==FNR&&$2=="80"{to[++x]=NR+5;from[x]=NR-5}
```

In the first file if the second field is 80 set to and from to the record number + or - whatever you want.
Increment the occurrence variable x.

```
NR!=FNR
```

In the second file

```
for(i in to)
```

For each occurrence

```
if(FNR<=to[i]&&FNR>=from[i]){print;next}
```

If the current record number(in this file) is between this occurrences to and from then print the line.Next prevents the line from being printed multiple times if occurrences of the pattern are close together.

```
file{,}
```

Use the file twice as two args. the `{,}` expands to `file file`